# SQL JSON functions

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, json.net, sql-server-2016

I'm getting a query output as follows from a table

```
RowId  QuestionGroupId QuestionId   Answer
  1           2             1       Single
  2           2             2       With Kids
  3           2             3       Not At All
  4           3             1       Single
  5           3             2       With Kids
  6           3             3       Occasionally Smoke
```

But the result I would Like to get is as something follows

```
RowId QuestionGroupId ValueSet
  1       2       [{QuestionId:1,Answer:Single},QuestionId:2,Answer:WithKids},QuestionId:3,Answer:Nt at all}]
  2       3       [{QuestionId:1,Answer:Single},QuestionId:2,Answer:WithKids},QuestionId:3,Answer:Occasionally Smoke}]
```

So how to I convert the rows of record to JSON using SQL JSON ability.

Using FOR JSON AUTO given me all in one row of record.Your help is appreciated.

Comment: SQL by itself doesn’t have any JSON functions. Please tag the database engine you’re using.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Thanks for the edit and making the question more readable.I'm using SQL server 2016 and it has certain amount of JSON function to parse the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really get what you're doing with the `RowId` column, but you should be able to do something like this with a correlated subquery to get what you're after

```
;with src 
(
    RowId,
    QuestionGroupId,
    QuestionId, 
    Answer
) as
(
    select 1, 2, 1, 'Single'
    union all select 2, 2, 2, 'With Kids'
    union all select 3, 2, 3, 'Not At All'
    union all select 4, 3, 1, 'Single'
    union all select 4, 3, 2, 'With Kids'
    union all select 4, 3, 3, 'Occasionally Smoke'
)
select
    QuestionGroupId,
    (
        select i.QuestionId, i.Answer
        from src i
        where o.QuestionGroupId = i.QuestionGroupId
        order by QuestionId
        for json auto

    ) as ValueSet
from src o
group by QuestionGroupId
```

Comment: that sounds perfect. I'll try with real tables of mine and mark as answer later on.